# How to solve this ODE by NDSolve?

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

I am trying to solve an ODE using NDSolve, but I get a division by zero error. I am not sure how to fix this and obtain a solution:

```
n=3;
g[e_,r_]=e*(2r^3/3 -r^2);
c=1/2;
H[e_,r_]=Integrate[s^2*(c-2*g[e,s]),{s,0,r}];
odeN= {(n-2)*r*f'[r]*Cot[f[r]]/Sqrt[1+(r*f'[r])^2]-D[r^3*f'[r]/Sqrt[1+(r*f'[r])^2],r]-(n-3)f'[r]/Sqrt[1+(r*f'[r])^2]==H[1,r], f[0] == 1,f'[0]==0}
solN= NDSolve[odeN, f, {r, 0, 20}];
pN=Plot[f[r]/. solN, {r, 0, 20}, PlotStyle -> {Blue}];
Show[pN,ImageSize->Large]
```

Is there a way around this issue?

Comment: Just for the test, change the initial point to a sufficiently small number instead of $0$, e.g. `f[0.0001] == 1, f'[0.0001] == 0` and `solN = NDSolve[odeN, f, {r, 0.0001, 20}]` then check the solution. It appears to have a singularity at `0`

Comment: It works but I get a warning: singularity or stiff system expected. Are there methods that deal with stiff/singular systems?

Answer (score 1):

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
n = 3;
g[e_, r_] = e*(2 r^3/3 - r^2);
c = 1/2;
H[e_, r_] = Integrate[s^2*(c - 2*g[e, s]), {s, 0, r}]
odeN = {(n - 2)*r*f'[r]*Cot[f[r]]/Sqrt[1 + (r*f'[r])^2] - 
     D[r^3*f'[r]/Sqrt[1 + (r*f'[r])^2], 
      r] - (n - 3) f'[r]/Sqrt[1 + (r*f'[r])^2] == H[1, r]};
ic = {f[$MachineEpsilon] == 1, f'[$MachineEpsilon] == 0}
solN = NDSolve[{odeN, ic}, f, {r, $MachineEpsilon, 20}, Method -> "StiffnessSwitching"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]